# R: add different values to columns within a list of dataframes

Tags: list, r, addition, dataframe

If I have a list like:

```
list <- list( "1" = data.frame(time=1:3, temp = sample(11:13)),
              "3" = data.frame(time=1:3, temp = sample(11:13)))

list

$`1`
  time temp
1    1   11
2    2   12
3    3   13

$`3`
  time temp
1    1   11
2    2   12
3    3   13
```

Now I want to add a correction-value to columns temp, +1 for dataframe 1 and -1 for dataframe 3, so the result would be:

```
$`1`
  time temp
1    1   12
2    2   13
3    3   14

$`3`
  time temp
1    1   10
2    2   11
3    3   12
```

Let´s additionally assume I have multiple of those lists, where sometimes dataframe 3 or 1 may be missing, or even a dataframe 2 maybe included, which would need its own correction-factor...
I tried strange things for dataframe 1:

```
list <- lapply(list, function(x)   {x <- x$"1"$temp-1;x})
```

or

```
list <- lapply(list, function(x)   {x <- x[x$temp+1,];x})
```

also tried to add a seq_along for the other dataframe in the list...nothing works, maybe because I don´t quite understand how the syntax works...

Comment: I'd give them a solid chance to edit what clearly is a snafu before downvoting...patience!

Comment: Ok I waited for the full question. But this is still too ambiguous to be answerable. Build a reproducible example that actually represents your full problem.

Comment: If this data is all the same size, it may be better to store it as a data.frame(), it would certainly simplify operations. If you want a quick and dirty way to convert back to a data.frame you can use df <- ldply(mylist) from the plyr package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the name of the data structure to dflist. It's just wrong to call a list "list". You also need some data structure to pull in the associated correction factors, so let's posit one with the same names as "dflist":

```
dflist <- list( "1" = data.frame(time=1:3, temp = sample(11:13)),
              "3" = data.frame(time=1:3, temp = sample(11:13)))

corrlist <- list("1" = 1, "3"=-1) 

# Replaced lapply with for loop
for( nam in names(dflist)) {
        dflist[[nam]]['temp'] <- dflist[[nam]]['temp'] +corrlist[[nam]]
                            }
 dflist
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Except a missing bracket at the end - and it deletes/overwrites the names/numbers of the dataframes. Instead of $`1` and $`3` the dataframes are marked with [[1]] and [[2]]. If I `return(dflist[x])` the names stay, but also those [[1]] are doubled O_o

Comment: The bracket was there (added space to emphasize) but there was a missing paren and your point about what I returned is well taken. Should have just returned dflist.

Comment: But other problems remain. Needs improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the loop. Looks as it should work....Unfortunately I also can´t figure out where the error is...

Comment: I don't get an error with that code. Is your R installation corrupted?

Comment: Oh sorry my fault. I did an `dflist <- for ...`, because I was kind of used to it... and I misunderstood your "problems remain. needs improvement" as a comment to the loop... - so you are right, it works nice and smoots :D